# Java Servlet Pooling

Tags: java, servlets, pooling

Servlets 101, under Tomcat 6:

Could someone kindly point me to a good explanation of the best way to eg. create a Collection of expensive Foo objects at servlet startup time and stash them somewhere where I can access them while processing each request?

Near as I can tell there are at least three ways to do this and I am a bit fuzzy on the difference. I am not concerned with clustering or algorithms to evict stale entries or anything like that, just the basics.

Cheers and Thanks.

Comment: what are those three ways you have found so far?

Comment: You didn't mention if the expensive objects can safely be used from multiple threads.  If not, you will have fewer options.

Answer (score 6):

Implement a [`ServletContextListener`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), do the desired loading task during `contextInitialized()` and store the result in the application scope by `ServletContext#setAttribute()`. It will be invoked during server's startup and the application scope is accessible inside regular servlets as well.

Basic example:

```
public class Config implements ServletContextListener {
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
        List<Foo> foos = fooDAO().list();
        event.getServletContext().setAttribute("foos", foos);
    }
}
```

Map it in `web.xml` the usual way:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>mypackage.Config</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Here's how to access it in regular servlets:

```
protected void doSomething(request, response) {
    List<Foo> foos = (List<Foo>) getServletContext().getAttribute("foos");
}
```

And here's how you can access it in JSPs:

```
<c:forEach items="${foos}" var="foo">
    ${foo.someProperty}<br>
</c:forEach>
```

That said, I really don't see how that is related to "servlet pool". This term makes no sense.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks,,,What is the main diference between contextInitialized interface method and init() ? could you clarify more ?

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- Use [commons-pool](http://commons.apache.org/pool/), initiate your objects at boot and then borrow them from the pool.
- Make sure that you really need a pool of objects. In many cases you can create just one object and access it in a thread safe manner. A good place to look is at the [spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for an object pool. Typically an object pool is built using a list of free objects, adding to the list when resources are freed while the maximum amount of free objects is not reached.

I would not fill the pool upfront, just allocate a new object if the pool of free objects is empty.

One notable performance win is to keep 1 reference for the last freed object. Not having to add it to the list of free objects saves a lot for situations where 1 object is allocated and freed alternatively. If the reference is not `null` add the next freed object to the list, on allocation return the last freed and `null` it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [servlet context](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html).

The servlet context is common to all servlets instances and its life cycle goes beyond the request and session.

You can put anything there like:

```
public void doGet( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) {

     ServletContext sc = getServletContext();

     List expensiveObjectList = ( List ) sc.getAttribute("someName");
     if( expensiveObjectList == null ) {
         expensiveObjectList = someExpensiveInitializationMethod();
         sc.setAttribute( "someName", expensiveObjectList );
     }

     // use the list... 
}
```

Here's a link where you can read more [about it](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnagl.html)